# Fix a position in a webcam video using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, video

I'm trying to draw an arrow to moving video using OpenCV.
What I want to do is the following:
Select a position (eg with the mouse) in the video captured by my webcam. Then I want to draw an arrow at this position. While the camera is moving the arrow should get drawn at the right position relatively to the webcam video.
Can you give some hints on how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "relatively to the webcam video"? Should it be drawn always at the same pixel position, or should it be drawn always at the same world position? I guess world position, so what you need is object/camera tracking, which is no simple task in general.

Comment: yeah exactly, it should be drawn always at the same "world position"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/abhi-kumar/OPENCV_MISC/blob/master/tracker.cpp) is pretty much what I'm looking for, but it isn't that stable. Since I'm a newbie to OpenCV, it would be helpful to get some help.